# ORA-01407:cannot update to null

Tags: oracle

My sql query for updating column "p1_high_edu_ctry" is:-

```
 update ps_personal_data J
 set (J.p1_high_edu_ctry) = (SELECT P.p1_high_edu_ctry FROM PS_PERS_DATA_EFFDT P 
 WHERE P.EFFDT=(SELECT MAX(K.EFFDT) FROM PS_PERS_DATA_EFFDT K
 WHERE K.EFFDT<=SYSDATE
 AND   J.EMPLID IN(SELECT H.EMPLID FROM PS_AUDIT_PER_EFFDT H 
 where h.AUDIT_OPRID='CHGH00000063232')))
 where exists(select 1 from PS_AUDIT_PER_EFFDT q where q.emplid=j.emplid) ;
```

but i m getting an error msg while updating:-

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01407: cannot update ("SYSADM"."PS_PERSONAL_DATA"."P1_HIGH_EDU_CTRY") to NULL
```

Any suggestions please,why its not working even if i am handling it with where exists???

Comment: I'm familiar with this EPM product, peoplesoft database you are using doesn't allow any nulls and i think you should check if row exists in `PS_PERS_DATA_EFFDT` also

Comment: yes,rows exists in PS_PERS_DATA_EFFDT.how to solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 MERGE INTO ps_personal_data J
 USING
 (
   SELECT P.p1_high_edu_ctry, p.emplid 
   FROM PS_PERS_DATA_EFFDT P 
   WHERE P.EFFDT=
              (
                SELECT MAX(K.EFFDT) FROM PS_PERS_DATA_EFFDT K
                WHERE K.EFFDT<=SYSDATE AND P.EMPLID = K.EMPLID 
                -- updated this condition , 
                -- you need to check max date by emplid 
                -- not max date from full table               
               )
   AND   P.EMPLID IN (SELECT H.EMPLID FROM PS_AUDIT_PER_EFFDT H 
                where h.AUDIT_OPRID='CHGH00000063232')
 ) v ON (J.emplid = v.emplid)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
 set J.p1_high_edu_ctry = nvl(v.p1_high_edu_ctry,' ');
```

Comment: it is giving error :-ERROR at line 13:
ORA-00969: missing ON keyword...why u are using merge instead of update??

Comment: make sure you are using exact query as above - `ON (J.emplid = v.emplid)` , i edited this query few min back. In your case your update should be done using joins and oracle doesn't support that, to update table with join conditions in oracle, you can use MERGE.

Comment: query is running fine but will this query creates new rows in ps_personal_data?I donot want to create new rows,only needs to update ps_personal_data with given criteria..

Comment: do you see any INSERT keyword in my code above? This will only UPDATE rows and not create new rows

Answer (score 1):

You have a not null constraint on this field while your subquery doesn't return any data, returning null. This is a documented behavior of [scalar subquery expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions010.htm#i1033549)

```
12:28:52 SYSTEM@dwal> create table n (t number not null);

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.31
12:39:18 SYSTEM@dwal> insert into n values (1);

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
12:40:12 SYSTEM@dwal> update n set t = (select 2 from dual where 1 = 2);
update n set t = (select 2 from dual where 1 = 2)
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01407: cannot update ("SYSTEM"."N"."T") to NULL


Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
```